# Are the lyrics of a poem / song on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Precise situation is this:  there's an old Christian song (1870's) for which there are a couple popular lyric versions.  I would like, if possible, to determine which one is the original.

Several things to note:

- It's not about a classic work
- It's not about a book

*... on the other hand ...*

- It is about a poem (literary form)
- It is about a well known Christian song

Should I hold my peace, or are such questions sufficiently within the scope of this site?